# Covariance problem involving and urn and some balls

Tags: probability, statistics

Okay so here is the question - Suppose we draw five balls from an urn without replacement. The urn has $5$ red, $6$ black, and $5$ green balls. If $X$ gives the number of green balls drawn and and $Y$ the number of red balls drawn, find $Cov(X,Y)$.

Here's my thought process so far $Cov(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}(XY) - \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$ so then I set it up into $Y_i$ {$1$ if $i^{th}$ draw is red, $0$ ELSE and then $X_i$ {$1$ if i$^{th}$ draw is green, $0$ ELSE}.

From here I changed it to $Cov(Y_i,X_i) = \mathbb{E}(Y_i X_i)-\mathbb{E}(Y_i)\mathbb{E}(X_i)$. This is as far as I can get and I don't even know if I'm on the right track here. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track.  As a general rule, $$Cov(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i,\sum_{j=1}^nY_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nCov(X_i,Y_j)$$

When $i=j, Cov(X_i,Y_j)=E(X_iY_j)-E(X_i)*E(Y_j)=0-({5\over 16}*{5\over 16})=-{25\over 256}$

Note that in this case $E(X_iY_j)=0$ since the same ball can't be red and green.

When $i\ne j, Cov(X_i,Y_j)=E(X_iY_j)-E(X_i)*E(Y_j)=({5\over 16}*{5\over 15})-({5\over 16}*{5\over 16})={5\over 768}$

Note that in this case $E(X_iY_j)={5\over 16}*{5\over 15}$ since the chance of any given ball being red is $5\over 16$ and the odds of a different ball being green is then $5\over 15$

We must now add all the covariances together and since $i=j$ five times and $i\ne j$ 20 times, we have $$Cov(X,Y)=5*-{25\over 256}+20*{5\over 768}=-{275\over 768}$$

Comment: This worked, I really do appreciate the help! Can I ask why you started using Xi and Yj though? I am at a loss as to where the j came into play and I would like to learn this type of problem as I hate being unable to complete a math problem.

Comment: I used two different variables for the subscripts because they don't always take on the same value.  If I used i for both, that would imply that they both always have the same value.

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed on the right track, except that you have to consider all $X_i$ and $Y_j$, not just $X_i$ and $Y_i$.  Next step: $\mathbb E(X_i Y_i) = 0$ because the $i$'th draw can't be both red and green.
What are $\mathbb E(X_i)$ and $\mathbb E(Y_i)$?

Another way of doing it is to consider the indicators for individual green and red balls, rather than draws.

Comment: I'm unsure of where I would begin to figure this out? Would a multinomial be the way to go as the draws are dependent?

Comment: One thing that makes it easier is that in computing probabilities for the $i$'th and $j$'th draws, you only need to consider those two draws: the fact that you're making other draws too, and the order in which you conduct the draws, are irrelevant.  Thus the probability of getting a green ball on draw 3 and a red ball on draw 5 is the same as the probability of getting a red ball on draw 1 and a green ball on draw 2.